# How to replace characters in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I'm a new SQL user, and I'd like to know if there is a simple way of replacing non-English characters in Oracle SQl-developer. Let's Say, I want Hernán Nuñez to show up as Hernan Nunez, but without having to actually replace "Hernán" with "Hernan". What I need is to replace everything that contains "á" to the same thing, but with "a" instead, for example. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a way of doing that for [SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578582/how-can-i-remove-accents-on-a-string), and there is another way of doing that for [Oracle Databases](https://community.oracle.com/thread/587783?start=0&tstart=0). But I'm confused, it is not clear which is your case.

Comment: @OlafDietsche The mentioned questions pertain to SQL Server. However, this question pertains to Oracle.

Comment: That's right, I'm using it on Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 7):

US7ASCII will give you the right result. Example:

```
SELECT CONVERT('BESANÇON','US7ASCII')
FROM table;

CONVERT(
--------
BESANCON
1 row selected.
```

Comment: +1 This query works perfectly! I tried this one too: `SELECT CONVERT('BÉSANÇON','US7ASCII') FROM DUAL;`

Comment: I have about 1600 users in that situation, is there a way to apply that to all of them in a doable manner?