# Convert Non-English text into English text using SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-function

I have text normalizing method, I use it to **convert non-English letters into English letters** only.

### I need to do the same functionality using SQL server

---

**C# Method:**

```
  private  string normalizeString(string inputWord)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (char c in inputWord.Trim().ToCharArray())
            {
                string normalizedChar = c.ToString()
                    .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Substring(0, 1);

                stringBuilder.Append(normalizedChar);
            }

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

---

**Example**

```
Ä => A
ä => a
Ö => O
ö => o
Õ => O
õ => o
Ü => U
ü => u
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit more? The letters 'A' and 'a' are called Latin letters, not English letters, in Unicode. They exist in multiple languages (e.g. Spanish, Italian), _not just English_. Are you trying to remove all diacritics? Or just certain diacritics? Or just diacritics over Latin letters? Or only letters that appear in Latin alphabet?. Because Cyrillic letters can have diacritics, too! How complex of an operation are you looking for? Unicode is hard. FWIW, [Unicode Normalization Forms are defined here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)

Comment: Yes I want to remove all diacritics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to remove diacritics you can use `Collate`

for example:

> select 'áéíóú' collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS

this will return "aeiou"

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578582/how-can-i-remove-accents-on-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

As per this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811976/normalize-unicode-string-in-sql-server) there's no such native function in SQL Server.
What you can do is to create a [CLR Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx) for that.