What is the function on T-SQL that allows me to convert western characters to oriental TEXT
What is the function on T-SQL that allows me to convert western characters to ocidental TEXT ?
It is not a translation, for example :
This Chinese word 越秀区东风东路 to this text Yuèxiù qū dōngfēng dōng lù, i can do this using python for example using unidecode function i need the same text result using t-sql.
Any thoughts ?

Is this a duplicate here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/31377772/125981

Don't think there is any out of the box. Perhaps you can wrap https://github.com/thecoderok/Unidecode.NET inside a CLR function? Or you can call python functions yourself from sql by using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 I suspect you don't need to do this in tsql though

This is something you should do in application code.

I think the term you're looking for is pinyin.

"What is the function on [sic] T-SQL" There isn't (a built-in) one. You would have to write your own solution. As @JoelCoehoorn suggests, this would be best in application code. If you "must" (you don't) do it in T-SQL, you very likely need to look into CLR. Though, you might be able to (ab)use sp_execute_external_script to run Python within SQL Server.

SQL Server doesn't have any native facility to translate between languages. The only thing that might make it appear that way is that you get error messages in your session language. This is because a human (well, a team of humans, and likely with the assistance of some software other than SQL Server) has done the translation and stored a different copy of the text for each language in sys.messages.

Aside... unidecode does not do exactly what you think it does, either. unidecode only outputs US-ASCII characters, so unidecode('越秀区东风东路') does not produce 'Yuèxiù qū dōngfēng dōng lù', it produces 'Yue Xiu Qu Dong Feng Dong Lu'. Regardless, Microsoft SQL Server has nothing built-in that does this, so do it in an external Python process or replicate the functionality in an SQL CLR function or procedure (which then gives you the opportunity to produce exactly the output you are seeking).

Does this answer your question? SQL Server Convert text from english to other language via an sp or function
