# Check If the string contains accented characters in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, diacritics, non-ascii-characters

I want to perform a task if the input string contain any accented characters else do another task in SQL. Is there any way to check this condition in SQL ?

Eg:

```
@myString1 = 'àéêöhello!'

IF(@myString1 contains any accented characters)
  Task1
ELSE
  Task2
```

Comment: I suspect there's some solution via the collate keyword; but not yet sure what it is.  Posting as a comment incase this inspires someone else... `collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Comment: You could probably just create a System constant with all accented characters as a checklist and then check via a regular expression?

Comment: What year of SQL server?

Comment: i have tried by creating a System constant with all accented characters as a checklist and then check , but i want a better way . And your answer full fills it. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7d/1607

```
declare @a nvarchar(32) = 'àéêöhello!'
declare @b nvarchar(32) = 'aeeohello!'

select case 
    when (cast(@a as varchar(32)) collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS) = @a 
    then 0 
    else 1 
end HasSpecialChars

select case 
    when (cast(@b as varchar(32)) collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS) = @b 
    then 0 
    else 1 
end HasSpecialChars
```

(based on solution here: [How can I remove accents on a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578582/how-can-i-remove-accents-on-a-string))

Answer (score 4):

I use this function to get text (mainly foreign family names) to a more comparable plain latin (with some indiv goodies - feel free to implement your own...).

Maybe you can use this too. Just compare, if your string is the same as the one passed back.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRunningNumbers](@anzahl INT=1000000, @StartAt INT=0)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(@anzahl,1000000)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A) -1 + ISNULL(@StartAt,0) AS Nmbr
    FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblA(A)
        ,(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblB(B)
        ,(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblC(C)
        ,(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblD(D)
        ,(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblE(E)
        ,(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tblF(F);

GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTextPlainLatin]
(
     @Txt VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@CaseSensitive BIT
    ,@KeepNumbers BIT
    ,@NonCharReplace VARCHAR(100),@MinusReplace VARCHAR(100) 
    ,@PercentReplace VARCHAR(100),@UnderscoreReplace VARCHAR(100) --for SQL-Masks
    ,@AsteriskReplace VARCHAR(100),@QuestionmarkReplace VARCHAR(100) --for SQL-Masks (Access-Style)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @txtTransformed VARCHAR(MAX)=(SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(@CaseSensitive,0)=0 THEN LOWER(@Txt) ELSE @Txt END)));
RETURN
(
    SELECT Repl.ASCII_Code
    FROM dbo.GetRunningNumbers(LEN(@txtTransformed),1) AS pos
    --ASCII-Codes of all characters in your text
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(@txtTransformed,pos.Nmbr,1)) AS ASCII_Code) AS OneChar  
    --re-code 
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('A') AND ASCII('Z') THEN  CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code)
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('a') AND ASCII('z') THEN  CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code)
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('0') AND ASCII('9') AND @KeepNumbers=1 THEN CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code)
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ƒ') THEN 'f'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Š') THEN 'S'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('š') THEN 's'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ß') THEN 'ss'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Ä') THEN 'Ae'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ä') THEN 'ae'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Æ') THEN 'Ae'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('æ') THEN 'ae'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Ö') THEN 'Oe'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ö') THEN 'oe'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Œ') THEN 'Oe'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('œ') THEN 'oe'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Ü') THEN 'Ue'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ü') THEN 'ue'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Ž') THEN 'Z'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ž') THEN 'z'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('×') THEN 'x'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('À') AND ASCII('Å') THEN  'A'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('à') AND ASCII('å') THEN  'a'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Ç') THEN 'C'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ç') THEN 'c'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('È') AND ASCII('Ë') THEN  'E'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('è') AND ASCII('ë') THEN  'e'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('Ì') AND ASCII('Ï') THEN  'I'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('ì') AND ASCII('ï') THEN  'i'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Ð') THEN 'D' --island Eth
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ð') THEN 'd' --island eth
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Ñ') THEN 'N'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ñ') THEN 'n'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('Ò') AND ASCII('Ö') THEN 'O'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('ò') AND ASCII('ö') THEN 'o'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Ø') THEN 'O'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ø') THEN 'o'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('Ù') AND ASCII('Ü') THEN  'U'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN ASCII('ù') AND ASCII('ü') THEN  'u'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Ý') THEN 'Y'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ý') THEN 'y'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Þ') THEN 'Th' --island Thorn
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('þ') THEN 'th' --island thorn
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('Ÿ') THEN 'Y'
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('ÿ') THEN 'y'
            --Special with "minus"
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('-') THEN ISNULL(@MinusReplace,ISNULL(@NonCharReplace,CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code)))
            --Special with mask characters
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('%') THEN ISNULL(@PercentReplace,ISNULL(@NonCharReplace,CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code)))
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('_') THEN ISNULL(@UnderscoreReplace,ISNULL(@NonCharReplace,CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code)))
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('*') THEN ISNULL(@AsteriskReplace,ISNULL(@NonCharReplace,CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code)))
            WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code = ASCII('?') THEN ISNULL(@QuestionmarkReplace,ISNULL(@NonCharReplace,CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code)))
            --replace others        
            ELSE ISNULL(@NonCharReplace,CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code))
        END AS ASCII_Code
    ) AS Repl    
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','varchar(max)');
END
GO

SELECT dbo.GetTextPlainLatin('Case sensitive ÄÖ àéêöhello!',1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
SELECT dbo.GetTextPlainLatin('Case in-sensitive ÄÖ àéêöhello!',0,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetTextPlainLatin
GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetRunningNumbers;
```

Answer (score 1):

A Crude way is to check `ASCII(<each character>) >= 128` for each character. Something like this

```
DECLARE @MyString NVARCHAR(100)
SET @MyString = N'àéêöhello!'

;WITH N as 
(
SELECT 1 r UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
), Numbers
as
(
SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N1.r) FROM N as N1 CROSS JOIN N as N2
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@MyString,RN,1)) >= 128 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ContainsAccentedChars FROM Numbers
WHERE RN <= LEN(@MyString)
```