# SQL Server 2012 : Convert 12Hr AM/PM nchar to 24Hr DateTime Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

First post/question here. I'm trying to convert an nchar to datetime. The examples I looked for all displayed converting to 12 hour from 24 or just dealing with time and not the full date with conversion. I'm not a native to SQL and I'm still learning the basics, so any help is appreciated.

I  have a table with this format that I've read from a bulk insert of .txt files.

Alarm is **nchar** of text,

AlarmTime is also **nchar** of the date I read from the text file.

```
Alarm    |    AlarmTime
  1      |      7/6/2016 10:10:42 AM
  2      |      7/10/2016 6:41:23 PM
  3      |      8/4/2016 4:35:53 PM
```

I would like to get this into a datetime format and not be store as nchar. 
Whenever I try to convert I get an error:
**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

The result I'm looking for is this just stored as datetime:

```
    Alarm    |    AlarmTime
      1      |      7/6/2016 10:10:42 
      2      |      7/10/2016 18:41:23 
      3      |      8/4/2016 16:35:53
```

I have considered separating the date and time in to separate columns using a delimiter and then putting them both back together later. Or using the PM to add time then convert the colum to datetime. But those both seemed cumbersome, and I figured there was something easy I was missing to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are on 2012, I would suggest that you use Try_Convert().  This will trap any conversion errors.   (Assuming your data string is m/d/y)

To identify the bogus records, try:

```
Select * from YourTable where Try_Convert(datetime,AlarmTime) is null
```

**Sample Code to Reformat your data**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Alarm int,AlarmTime nvarchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(  1,'7/6/2016 10:10:42 AM'),
(  2,'7/10/2016 6:41:23 PM'),
(  3,'8/4/2016 4:35:53 PM')

Select A.*
      ,ReFormated = format(try_convert(datetime,AlarmTime),'M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
      ,AsDateTime = try_convert(datetime,AlarmTime)
 From  @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
Alarm   AlarmTime               ReFormated          AsDateTime
1       7/6/2016 10:10:42 AM    7/6/2016 10:10:42   2016-07-06 10:10:42.000
2       7/10/2016 6:41:23 PM    7/10/2016 18:41:23  2016-07-10 18:41:23.000
3       8/4/2016 4:35:53 PM     8/4/2016 16:35:53   2016-08-04 16:35:53.000
```

Comment: I haven't heard of try_convert. But I ran and completed without errors, however the colum remains null. Following and running your example code everything runs correctly. So I think my issue may be with how I'm reading in and storing my date in the colum. I'll try removing any leftover spaces and see if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: @Spex1848 Happy it helped.  I suspected some bogus data.  Always risky storing datetimes as a string... too many things can go wrong.

Comment: @Spex1848 Just curious  when you ran Select * from YourTable where Try_Convert(datetime,AlarmTime) is null   how many records where returned?  All or just a handful?

Comment: I just tried again using LTRIM. When I run the select you described above it returns all of the records. So that means at no point did i get a proper conversion. I'm pretty sure now that the issue is with the string I'm passing. Trying now to see how I can get that in order then test out converting again. Thanks again!

Comment: @Spex1848 see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148767/sql-server-remove-all-non-printable-ascii-characters/43149139#43149139   Perhaps you have control characters in your string