# Is there any way to save strings in SQL Server database without white space?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server database, when strings are saved they have a lot of white space.

Is there any way to remove them in the database, by updating the table, or when new information is entered?

Comment: Why would you need to redesign the table? Just do "update your_table set your_col = trim(your_col)" to remove the whitespace (I assume "white text" means whitespace). And to prevent it from happening in the future, you could modify your insert procedure to do a trim operation on the input.

Comment: Using compression while reduce the size if the white spaces are in the middle of the data.  You would need to uncompress when reading.

Comment: Whats the datatype? If you are using nvarchar, you should not have such a problem.

Comment: @LegacyCode Perfect! Thanks to you, I can delete all my 'trimFromDB' functions... post as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: If open to a helper function... Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148767/sql-server-remove-all-non-printable-ascii-characters/43149139#43149139

Comment: I presume from comments above that you were using a fixed width datatype such as `nchar` or `char`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) Change your data type to NVARCHAR