# How can I use a string from array to search for string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in my SQL Server table (see example below). I need to write a query that will return the rows containing a given string, for instance `830`. However, I need to search for any string within an string array.

As an example:

- I have a string array like this '634,7,830'.
- Call my query with '634,7,830' as input
- Result should be row 3, 5, 6, and 7

[image]

This is as far as I am, but here I only get the last three rows and not the one containing '830'.

How can I get the missing one?

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.YYY
WHERE [DepartmentNo] IN (SELECT value 
                         FROM STRING_SPLIT('634,7,830', ','))
```

[image]

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support arrays data types; in fact (in my opinion) no *good* RDBMS should. A value in a RDBMS should represent an **atomic** value; that means it's it represents a single specific value. The *real* thing you need to do here is fix your design and normalise your data.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Perhaps this will help

```
-- Just a Demonstrative Table Variable.

Declare @YourTable Table ([DepartmentNo] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('403,273,828')
,('403,273,829')
,('403,273,830')
,('403,273,831')
,('634')
,('634')
,('7')

-- The Actual Query
 
Select * 
 from @YourTable A
 cross apply string_split([DepartmentNo],',') B
 Where B.value in (select * from string_split('634,7,830',','))
```

**Results**

```
DepartmentNo    value
403,273,830     830
634             634
634             634
7               7
```

**Here is a SVF to strip Control Characters**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[svf-Str-Strip-Control](@S varchar(max))
Returns varchar(max)
Begin
    Select @S=Replace(@S,char(n),' ')
     From  (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31) ) N(n)

    Return ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(@S,' ','†‡'),'‡†',''),'†‡',' ')))
End
--Select [dbo].[svf-Str-Strip-Control]('Michael        '+char(13)+char(10)+'LastName')  --Returns: Michael LastName
```

**Then Updated Answer**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([DepartmentNo] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('403,273,828')
,('403,273,829')
,('403,273,830'+char(8))  -- Notice char(8)
,('403,273,831')
,('634')
,('634')
,('7')
 
Select * 
 from @YourTable A
 cross apply string_split([dbo].[svf-Str-Strip-Control]([DepartmentNo]),',') B
 Where B.value in (select * from string_split('634,7,830',','))
```

**Results same as above or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=90459c3f86712c1ba26c1d8bf84235a1)**

Comment: Hi John. Does this work for you in SQL Server? I still only get 634;634;7 when I try your query

Comment: .. replacing “cross apply” with “where exists” would not return duplicates when two or more of the search values match the same department . eg search for(‘403,273‘)

Comment: @Birch78  Yes this works in SQL Server  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=925b9f2d8a41d2c4e434a48baaf517cb  .   Perhaps you have trailing control characters such as tabs or CRLFs

Comment: @lptr  OP is not looking for distinct values.   Clearly stated desired rows "3, 5, 6, and 7"

Comment: That is super strange. I did a copy paste of your code and replaced the @YourTable with the name of my table

Comment: @Birch78 I added a control character and notice it is now excluded from the results https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f4dc33dc116bacf19c028b0b97228a77

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148767/sql-server-remove-all-non-printable-ascii-characters/43149139#43149139  to strip control characters

Comment: Ahh now I see your point. In the query you provided is it possible to trim both my array and [DepartmentNo]? There might be white spaces

Comment: @Birch78 Just to be clear.  Odds are you've got the stray tab or CLRF ... the function provided may be overkill, but it does eliminate the hunt-and-peck

Comment: Hi John. You are awesome, thanks a lot. I just need to figure out how to use functions in SQL but it seams it does what I need.

Comment: As far as I can see your code only trim tailing whitespace and not leading whitespace, right?

Comment: @Birch78  Just a random after thought.   Before you try the function, you may want to remove spaces.    ... cross apply string_split(replace([DepartmentNo],' ',''),',') B ...

Comment: The function removes leading and trailing control control characters, but you may only have extra spaces.    Look at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c3a3cace170a59291515b286c214188f