# Remove all white space from end from string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have string for eg : `'test 123 Add  '`. I want to remove last 2 white space from string, the space count is dynamic. `RTRIM()` function is not working on my case. I am using the following query, but it removes only static value from last.

```
Left(mycolumndata,len(mycolumndata)-1)
```

Please suggest me best solution.

Comment: What's wrong with `TRIM`/`LTRIM`/`RTRIM`? You say it "isn't working", what do you mean by this? Are there, perhaps *other* characters other than whitespace? Those functions, by default, only remove whitespace, not other characters.

Comment: Does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 answer your question?

Comment: You'll want to link to the English documentation, @Reporter , not the German .

Comment: @Larnu Yes, I didn't notice that google gave me the german version^^ I edited the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Be aware - if you're *storing* these values in fixed-length columns (`(N)CHAR` instead of `(N)VARCHAR`), you always have the trailing spaces.

Comment: Also, for the *single* value you have given, both `TRIM` and `RTRIM` work fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6fb0e0e009fa974e072872e3b4c76664).

Comment: Odds are you only have some trailing control characters like CRLF or TAB.   That said, this function may help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148767/sql-server-remove-all-non-printable-ascii-characters/43149139#43149139

Comment: What you ask for is exactly what `rtrim` does - can you supply sample data that illustrates it not working?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever both `TRIM` and `RTRIM` convert the data type to a `varchar`/`nvarchar`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=679547a6c8d3192748965873d79e22c5)

Comment: @Larnu - I was meaning in a context where e.g. they're running this as an `UPDATE` to try to clean the data - if it's being stored *back* into a `char` then it gains the trailing spaces back again. I have seen people trying to do this.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense , @Damien_The_Unbeliever .

Comment: "`RTRIM()` function is not working on my case." Please note that `RTRIM` only removes regular spaces. If your string contains tabs, newlines, non-breaking spaces or other more exotic whitespace characters, then this may help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132966/trim-whitespace-spaces-tabs-newlines

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely that you're trailing whitespace includes things other than spaces. The most common culprits are Tabs (CHAR(9)), and like breaks CHAR(10) and CHAR(13). Using [Ngrams8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) you can easily identify the problem; consider this example:

```
DECLARE 
  @string VARCHAR(100) = 'test 123 Add
      '
```

I include a tab, a couple spaces and more. Using Ngrams8k we can do this:

```
SELECT ng.Position, ng.Token, [ascii] = ASCII(ng.Token)
FROM   dbo.ngrams8k(@string,1) AS ng;
```

**Returns:**

[image]

Here we can use [TRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples).

THE MOST IMPORTANT THING TO KNOW ABOUT TRIM IS THAT **IT IS NOT `RTRIM(LTRIM(` !!!**
TRIM is power-packed and is intended for handling more than whitespace; note this example from the documentation:

[image]

The culprit in this example are CHAR(9)'s (10)'s and (13)'s. Armed with this knowledge we can use TRIM like so.

```
DECLARE 
  @string VARCHAR(100) = 'test 123 Add
      ',
  @trim VARCHAR(10) = CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(32);

SELECT TRIM(@trim FROM  @string) AS Result;
```

If you are not on 2019 you can always do this:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(@string,1,
    DATALENGTH(@string) - PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',REVERSE(@String))+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a text editor like `notepad++` or `EmEditor`, you can copy/paste the data you're having issues with, turn on `show all characters`, and figure out exactly what those characters are so you can account for them in your code. as Alan says above, the usual suspects are `CHAR(10)` and `CHAR(13)` `(CR/LF)`. -D