# Extract substring before whitespace of varying length in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a particular column, I am trying to extract everything before any whitespace. For example in the string `"text1   text2"` there are three spaces between "text1" and "text2", and I just want text 1.

But within this same column there could be a string like `"text1     text2"`, and here there are 5 spaces in between text1 and text2.

I tried the following code:

```
SELECT LEFT(column, CHARINDEX(' ', column) -1 )
```

But as I quickly learned, this would only work on strings where there is only one space in between the two words.

Any idea on how I can index for whenever any whitespace appears in a string?

Comment: Why do you feel that the above would only work when there is only 1 space? `LEFT('text1    text2', CHARINDEX(' ', 'text1    text2') -1 )` returns `'text1'`; why is that *not* correct?

Comment: Is it a [space] or perhaps some other control character(s)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148767/sql-server-remove-all-non-printable-ascii-characters/43149139#43149139

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Agree with @JohnCappelletti. While _space_ is a _whitespace_ character it doesn't follow that _whitespace_ will always be a _space_ character. Depending on context whitespace often includes other characters like tabs, carriage returns, linefeeds, non-breaking spaces, etc.. If you `select cast('text1   text2' as varbinary(max))` you will see `20` representing space characters, do you see other things like tab `09`, carriage return `0D`, linefeed `0A` in the output?

Comment: `LEFT(column, NULLIF(PATINDEX('[^A-Za-z0-9]', column), 0) -1 )` should do the trick