# Replace Funny Character in a String in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help to replace funny character in a column in SQL Server,

I have data like this:

```
id        itemDesc
----------------------------------------------
1         Ball lock pins/ spring typeáááááá
2         Res 1.5k Ohm û R0805 1%
```

If `itemDesc` contains `á`, then replace it with `" "`; if it contains (`û`), replace it with `-`. I used `charindex` but not change at all especially with many funny characters like id = 1, so if i used charindex, "Ball lock pins/ spring typeáááááá" => "Ball lock pins/ spring type ááááá"

Any approach?
thanks for help

Comment: You need to use `replace`.

Comment: Do you only care about those 2 special characters?  FYI: You can change the collation to remove all accents; e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32047075/361842 - different to what you've specified in your question, but perhaps gives an alternate solution to your underlying issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) to replace the characters on the string:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(itemDesc, 'á', ' '), 'û', '-') FROM table_name
```

In case you want to `UPDATE` the value on column `itemDesc` you can use the following:

```
UPDATE table_name SET itemDesc = REPLACE(REPLACE(itemDesc, 'á', ' '), 'û', '-')
```

The function [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) can't be used to replace the characters, but to find them. So you can `UPDATE` or `SELECT` only the rows with these characters using [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(itemDesc, 'á', ' '), 'û', '-') 
FROM table_name
WHERE CHARINDEX('á', itemDesc) > 0 OR CHARINDEX('û', itemDesc) > 0

UPDATE table_name SET itemDesc = REPLACE(REPLACE(itemDesc, 'á', ' '), 'û', '-')
WHERE CHARINDEX('á', itemDesc) > 0 OR CHARINDEX('û', itemDesc) > 0
```

> **demo:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6e241/1/0

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SQL Server 2017, you can use [`TRANSLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(itemDesc, 'áû',' -') AS itemDescTidy
FROM table_name;
```

This is a little more succinct than a nested `REPLACE` (but is actually identical, as it's a "short-hand" function).