# SQL code to find and suppress numbers and special characters

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql

I want to include/modify in my SQL code to be able to eliminate the following characters: '&%
-single quotes 
-ampersand 
-percentage

I need to include any of this characters in the current REGEX.
Thanks in advance

```
DECLARE @counter int;
SET @counter = 0
WHILE(@counter < (SELECT MAX(ID_COLUMN) FROM [dbo].[zzIntegriyCheckV4HistoryClient_TEMP]))

BEGIN  
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[zzIntegriyCheckV4HistoryClient_TEMP] WHERE MESSAGE NOT LIKE '% must be between %')
    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @RetVal varchar(50)

        SET @RetVal =  (SELECT MESSAGE = STUFF(MESSAGE, PATINDEX('%[0-9()$%&/.:!]%', MESSAGE),1, '')
        FROM [dbo].[zzIntegriyCheckV4HistoryClient_TEMP]
        WHERE ID_COLUMN = @counter)

        IF(@RetVal IS NOT NULL)       
          UPDATE [dbo].[zzIntegriyCheckV4HistoryClient_TEMP] SET MESSAGE = @RetVal WHERE ID_COLUMN = @counter
        ELSE
            break
    END

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Comment: If you read the description of the SQL tag you added, it encourages the addition of a tag for the specific DBMS you're using as well, as functionality and syntax differs between them. Please [edit] your post to do so.

Comment: The tag [tsql] points to SQL Server (although this is not sure). You might read [about TRANSLATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (needs v2017+)

Answer (score 0):

This is a blind shot as you did not specify your RDBMS. But assuming your `[tsql]` is pointing to SQL-Server and you have a version v2017+, you might try this:

--some muddy input

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100)='abc123(33)%&$.def,,3xyz';
```

--a list of all characters you want to get rid of

```
DECLARE @notWanted VARCHAR(100)='0123456789!"§$%&/()=?*+-_#''<>@€,.;:';
```

--an intermediate placeholder (any of the forbidden characters)

```
DECLARE @useInstead CHAR(1)='~';
```

--Here you see the work of TRANSLATE()

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(@input,@notWanted,REPLICATE(@useInstead,LEN(@notWanted)));
--> abc~~~~~~~~~~~~def~~~xyz
```

--Now you can use a simple REPLACE()

```
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE(@input,@notWanted,REPLICATE(@useInstead,LEN(@notWanted))),@useInstead,'')
--> abcdefxyz
```

Hint: Before anybody starts to offer a huge answer with a recursive CTE, loops, tally lists and so on please provide more details.
You might read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32048968/5089204) where I provided a function to deal with each character separately. You can adapt this to your needs.